# Misfired pointer events in nested iframes on Chromium 78

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, chromium

First of, this looks like a chromium bug and I already submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1021508). It's moving slowly so I'm opening a question here mainly for a **workaround solution** if anyone else has come across similar or related issues.

Also, code examples are not HTML5 compliant for readability reasons. I'm just showing a reduced example.

#### Description

In Chrome 78 and Edge beta, when there are 2+ nested iframes with different origin and there is an overlapping element, *pointerout/pointerover* events are misfiring between each click inside the iframe - only when there is at least 1px movement between *pointerdown* and *pointerup*. On Chrome 77, Edge stable, Firefox and Safari these events fire only when the pointer leaves the iframe or enters it respectively, which is the correct and expected behaviour.

When removing the overlapping element, Chrome 78 behaves as expected but Edge beta doesn't (Edge beta is unaffected by the overlapping element case).

When setting the iframe origins to be similar (ex. Both localhost), it behaves as expected in both browsers.

#### Reproduction

Start a server (like http-server for simplicity) in a folder containing the following files

a.html

```
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:[port]/b.html"></iframe>
<div style="height: 3px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 159px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 0px;
    background: green;"></div>
```

b.html

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:[port]/c.html"></iframe>
```

c.html

```
<button id="btn">Click</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    
    btn.addEventListener('pointerdown', function() { console.log('down'); });
    btn.addEventListener('pointerup', function() { console.log('up'); });
    btn.addEventListener('pointerover', function() { console.log('over'); });
    btn.addEventListener('pointerout', function() { console.log('out'); });
    btn.addEventListener('pointerleave', function() { console.log('leave'); });
</script>
```

Navigate to localhost/a.html click button and check console for the event logs.

[image]

Note that the iframe origins in a.html and b.html are different. With that setting if you navigate to 127.0.0.1 it behaves correctly but on localhost it doesn't.

If you move the div in a.html outside the iframes it works. (Chrome 78 only)

#### Question

Any potential workarounds? Ideally through JS or CSS as messing with the iframe origin and domains is not always possible nor the best solution.

Regarding overlapping div, sometimes messing with z-index works but again it's not the best solution as iframes can have overlapping elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea for a workaround: you could compare the coordinates in the out/leave events to the last known position inside the button element. If the coordinates are the same then ignore the out/leave events. Also you may need to handle blur event as well.

So lets say you have a down handler that sets some variables (like current position, pressed state) and also subscribes to move event.

Your move handler just updates the current position.

Your out/leave handler compares the current position to the event position. If they are equal and there was no blur event then ignore this event and return from the handler. Otherwise cancel the press, reset variables, unsubscribe from move etc.